# I can not get this UIView round

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

This is the final result of the code below:

[image]

This is my code:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * view.bounds.size.width
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
view.clipsToBounds = true
```

view is the red UIView. This code is placed in viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews (not together, but I both tested them).

Besides this SO is not clear about using masksToBounds OR clipsToBounds. I am not sure what to use and when to use one of them above. I also tested it apart.

The green UIView has also clipsToBounds active and rounded corners, but if I remove them both, I still get the same effect... I hope someone can help. **This only occurs when I place a UIView, inside another UIView**. If the UIView does not has a parent, it works (I get the UIView rounded).

Edit: GitHub link: https://github.com/Jasperav/tests

Comment: Is that view.bounds.size.width = view.bounds.size.height ?

Comment: The view as a 1:1 aspect ratio

Comment: make sure the view height and width should even number for example view h = 10, w =10 then corner radius = 5

Comment: Could you describe what want you achieve?

Comment: You'll need to show a little more code for what you are doing with your views. Are you adding the red view to the green view as a subview? Or as a sublayer? Are you setting the red view's corner radius and *then* changing the size of the green view? Are the views positioned / sized with auto-layout and constraints?

Comment: Everything is positioned with Autolayout, the red view is a subview inside the green view. Even if I do not change the size of the green view and just change the corner radius of the red view, I get this strange effect... I can upload my project on Github when I get home

Comment: @DonMag GitHub file is : https://github.com/Jasperav/tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with when the auto-layout engine actually finishes all the layout calculations.

If you move your code to `viewDidAppear` you will see properly "rounded" corners.

This is a very common case for using a custom view though. In fact, it's easily used as an "IBDesignable" class, so you can see it rendered in Interface Builder.

Create a new file named "RoundedView.swift" with this code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * self.bounds.size.height
    }
}
```

Then assign that class to the View you want to be round. Xcode will build your new class, and it will show up in Interface Builder like so:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I actually want to use the class "SpringView" for my UIView (Spring is a pod file), so I can not use this separately ( can not use 2 classes). Is it possible to make an extension for a regular UIView?